# Can I easily replace keys in the new 2016 MacBook Pro?

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

I am using the Dvorak keyboard map on my Mac, I used to just switch keys from the keyboard to have a nice Dvorak keyboard.

Does any one know if there is a simple way to replace keys on the new Mac Book Pro released this last fall?

Comment: Why don't you just stick to usual keyboard skin? If you used Dvorak a lot, you will remember it in heart before long (though I don't use it), like every process of learning a new input method.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed two keys on mine: can't believe there's no good info out there on this yet. The clips are on all four corners of the key, but you should only pry the top edge of the key as the clips on the bottom are designed to slide off toward the bottom, rather than pull straight up. I used a thin piece of plastic (the plastic-only edge of a laminated tag) to pry the top edge. A credit card would probably work but might be a little stiff for the initial pry.

Once you have the top clips off slide the key down until the bottom clips are off as well. It's a nice flat surface underneath, I had no qualms about cleaning with a damp cloth. To replace the key slide the bottom clips on in an upward direction, then press the top clips into place once the key is centered in place.

Answer (score 0):

I also have rearranged my physical keys to the Dvorak layout on my past machines and am concerned about being able to do so on my 2016 model. I think it will be significantly harder than previous years, but considering it's been done with the Macbook's butterfly keyboard, which was even shallower, I think we might be able to do it.

You may want to look into what tools iFixit uses to pry off keycaps.

I think the best tool will be something thin without a sharp point so that the force is distributed throughout the key. You can see that in iFixit's teardown, they broke part of the key: https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/Xoa5bxb5rwbDjJTf.huge. Perhaps prying up from a corner would be better than a long side?

Here's a short video of someone prying up a function key, including the underlying butterfly mechanism (which we shouldn't need to do): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b-8xqB0_jo

Answer (score -1):

Eventually someone will start making keyboard covers like this type of thing: https://www.amazon.ca/Kuzy-AIR-11inch-Keyboard-Silicone-KEYBOARD/dp/B007XYKEMK and then you'll be able to buy one with whatever characters you want on it.

Ok, here is one already avaiable, but more than a few bucks:

http://kbcovers.com/dvorak-keyboard-cover/

Or you can pop-off and rearrange the keys:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCT-CldP_r4

Comment: Hi thanks, Using cover makes the typing not as direct/fast so I actually like better to rearrange the keys, that was actually my question.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the new keyboard on the new macbook pro from this fall can also be modified this way (or basically, will I ruin my new Mac if I try to do it...)