# How hard is it to replace keys on a MacBook Pro 14’ (2021)?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, maintenance

This is possibly a duplicate if the difficulty of changing the keys for keyboard for a MacBook Pro [hasn’t changed since 2016](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264750/can-i-easily-replace-keys-in-the-new-2016-macbook-pro) but even then, my question differs slightly.

What I’m really interested in knowing is how challenging it is to replace individual keys for this kind of keyboard (M1 MacBook Pro 14’ 2021); more specifically, what kind of skill level is required to successfully do it? If I’m just a normal person who is careful and watches a YouTube video, is there still a good chance that I could ruin the keyboard? Are the keys soldered on or are they entirely detachable via some kind of mechanism, etc.

[Related Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429124/what-is-the-key-mechanism-on-the-macbook-pro-2021-keyboard) that doesn’t quite answer what I’m looking for; it identified that the keyboard hasn’t changed since 2019, but I suppose that implies there was a change in 2019, meaning the 2016 answer may not be applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to look would be https://support.apple.com/self-service-repair Even if you don't intend to do it yourself, the guide for your specific model will give you an idea of the scale of the job. A random YT video is always going to gloss over some salient point, so the proper guide is to be preferred.

There are specific key types for specific keyboard layouts, and the mechanisms have changed at some point too, so older guides may not be relevant anymore. The section on replacing keys starts at pg 22 in your particular model's guide (same as mine, so I've a passing familiarity with it).

All that said, the prerequisites are quite extensive, and although the public are 'allowed' (if that's the right stress) to do their own repairs, I think the intended audience is very much the very serious amateur, or 3rd-party pro repair shop.