# Replacing MacBook Pro M1 Screen Replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, apple-silicon, repair

I have a 13-inch MacBook Pro M1 and my screen is broken. I found another MBP, same version exactly, from a friend of mine. I would like to know if I can replace my screen with the one from my friends laptop.

Am I able to do it or I will face any problem with serial numbers?

Comment: Is your friend's laptop broken? If not, it soon will be without a display. If it's working why not just make a deal of some sort with your friend, and restore your system onto the 'new' machine?

Answer (score 1):

Apple now allow 3rd party repairs with certain kit, in as much as they will supply parts and tools. See https://support.apple.com/self-service-repair

The same advice as for https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448825/221742 applies here, although this isn't a duplicate, you're asking about the screen.

Note that the prerequisites for doing it properly are quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I able to do it or I will face any problem with serial numbers?

Currently, MacBook Air/Pro components are not serialized like the iPhones are<sup>1</sup>.  [You can obtain replacement parts](https://support.apple.com/self-service-repair) like the display assembly or top case assembly (keyboard and track pad) without needing to “marry” the component to the logic board.

So, in short, yes you can use your friends donor machine for parts.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Is This the End of the Repairable iPhone?](https://www.ifixit.com/News/45921/is-this-the-end-of-the-repairable-iphone), iFixit News, October 29, 2020.